# Unwanted React Component rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, states

So this is a form where the user can add sections to add a question (to build a quiz) and I notice that when I fill in the `Answer Choices` and put a file in my `dropZone` (drop works but doesn't update correctly, you can ignore this) the `Answer Choices` and `dropZone` rerender and the fields like refresh and become empty.

I am not entirely sure why this is happening, i have tried looking at similar issues but I couldn't get it to work. [Here is my CodeSandbox with my App.](https://codesandbox.io/s/1vy36n4wy4)

I am thinking that it may be the `addQuestion` function in my `Questions` component. Here's the code for that:

```
  addQuestion = question => {
    questionIdx++;
    var newQuestion = { uniqueId: uuid(), question: "" }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      questions: [...prevState.questions, newQuestion]
    }));
    return { questions: newQuestion }
  };
```

I am new to React and Js so any tips/explanations will do loads of help. Thanks!

Comment: I can't produce the problem you define here. I click and put a file but fields stays the same.

Comment: After filling in the input fields add another question. When the `Add Question` button is pressed those inputs rerender

Comment: So, the problem is not related with putting file. Also, I can't quite understand your code. You use `this.handleUpdate`, `this.value` and `this.index` in your `AddQuestionButton` to pass `Question` but those are not belong to this class. And, `this.props.onClick` is a function here and you are passing a component to it?

Comment: I took out what was inside of the `this.props.onClick` thing in the `AddQuestionButton` component, so now it's   `addQuestion = () => {
    this.props.onClick(
    );
  };` There doesn't seem to be a change to what goes on with the form, so I don't think it was doing anything

Comment: @devserkan I have updated my question with more information and some updated code, let me know if you need anything else, I am still having difficulties finding a solution to this

Comment: You are overthinking and writing complex and probably faulty codes. In your `AddQuestionButton` component takes a prop name `onClick` which points `this.addQuestion` function. You are invoking this function in your `AddQuestionButton`. But, `addQuestion` function takes an argument named `question`. Where does this argument coming from? I can't see it. If you are new to React, think simple. Start with simple components and widen them. Honestly, I tried to follow your code but it is very hard. At least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new question, and update the `Questions` components state variable `questions` (Array type), the whole component (`Questions` and its children) goes through an update process where it recalculates the output DOM tree (a virtual DOM) based on the new state and compares it to the pre-state-change virtual DOM. Before anything is 'rerendered' it checks to see if the virtual DOMs of the two versions are different among other things, if they are it will rerender the parts that change as efficiently as possible.

In your case, the recalculation sees many `Answers` component inside of many `Question` and since `Answers` doesn't have any props, it is basically a fresh render to its initial state which includes 4 empty inputs. The simplest solution I can think of is in the state of the `Questions` component, make sure each object in the `this.state.questions` Array has an `answers` attribute (of type Array of Objects). In the `addQuestion` method modify `var newQuestion = { uniqueId: uuid(), question: "" };` to includes this data on the answers related to that question.

Then when rendering each individual question, pass this answer data (Array of answers) as a prop to `Answers` and in turn to each individual `Answer` component based on the index (an Object or a String). At the same time, you must pass an `updateAnswers` method as a prop to `Question` that in turn is passed to `Answers` and `Answer`, that is called when an `Answer`s input field is changed. The question id and the id of the answer needs to be passed to this method to ultimately modify the answer data that should be now stored in the state of the `Questions` component. I adjusted the code from the sandbox below to work along these lines, although I didn't make sure to cleanup all the damage:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

var uuid = require("uuid-v4");
// Generate a new UUID
var myUUID = uuid();
// Validate a UUID as proper V4 format
uuid.isUUID(myUUID); // true

class DropZone extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: "",
      fileId: uuid(),
      className: "dropZone"
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this._onDragEnter = this._onDragEnter.bind(this);
    this._onDragLeave = this._onDragLeave.bind(this);
    this._onDragOver = this._onDragOver.bind(this);
    this._onDrop = this._onDrop.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(file = "") {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(file)
    });
    //document.getElementsByClassName("dropZone").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.state.file + ')';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    window.addEventListener("dragenter", this._onDragEnter);
    window.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    document
      .getElementById("dragbox")
      .addEventListener("dragleave", this._onDragLeave);
    window.addEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", this._onDragLeave);
    window.removeEventListener("dragenter", this._onDragEnter);
    window.addEventListener("dragover", this._onDragOver);
    document
      .getElementById("dragbox")
      .removeEventListener("dragleave", this._onDragLeave);
    window.removeEventListener("drop", this._onDrop);
  }

  _onDragEnter(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  }

  _onDragLeave(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  _onDrop(e, event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.handleChange(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    let files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    console.log("Files dropped: ", files);
    // Upload files
    console.log(this.state.file);
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    const uniqueId = this.state.fileId;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="file"
          id={uniqueId}
          name={uniqueId}
          class="inputFile"
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.files[0])}
        />
        <label htmlFor={uniqueId} value={this.state.file}>
          {this.props.children}
          <div className="dropZone" id="dragbox" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            Drop or Choose File
            <img src={this.state.file} id="pic" name="file" accept="image/*" />
          </div>
        </label>
        <div />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Answers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answers: props.answers,
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  // let event = {
  //   index: 1,
  //   value: 'hello'
  // };
  handleUpdate(event) {
    //if ("1" == 1) // true
    //if ("1" === 1) //false
    // var answers = this.state.answers;
    // answers[event.index] = event.value;
    // this.setState(() => ({
    //   answers: answers
    // }));

    var answers = this.state.answers.slice();

    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
      if (answers[i].answerId == event.answerId) {
        answers[i].answer = event.value;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState(() => ({
      answers: answers
    }));
    this.props.updateAnswers(answers)

    console.log(event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="answers">
        Answer Choices<br />
        {this.state.answers.map((value, index) => (
          <Answer
            key={`${value}-${index}`}
            onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
            value={value}
            number={index}
            name="answer"
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Answer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answer: props.value.answer,
      answerId: props.value.answerId,
      isCorrect: props.value.isCorrect,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({
      answer: value
    });
    this.props.onUpdate({
      answerId: this.state.answerId,
      value
    });

    // let sample = {
    //   kyle: "toast",
    //   cam: "pine"
    // };

    // sample.kyle
    // sample.cam
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.answer}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          key={this.state.answerId}
          name="answer"
        />
        {/*console.log(this.state.answerId)*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var questionIdx = 0;

class Questions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      questions: []
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    this.removeQuestion = this.removeQuestion.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate(event) {
    //if ("1" == 1) // true
    //if ("1" === 1) //false
    var questions = this.state.questions.slice();

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (questions[i].uniqueId == event.uniqueId) {
        questions[i].question = event.value;
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState(() => ({
      questions: questions
    }));

    console.log(event, questions);
  }

  updateAnswers(answers, uniqueId) {
    const questions = this.state.questions
    questions.forEach((question) => {
      if (question.uniqueId === uniqueId) {
        question.answers = answers
      }
    })
    this.setState({
      questions,
    })
  }

  addQuestion = question => {
    questionIdx++;
    var newQuestion = { 
      uniqueId: uuid(),
      question: "",
      answers: [
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false,},
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false,},
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false,},
        { answer: "", answerId: uuid(), isCorrect: false,}]
      }
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      questions: [...prevState.questions, newQuestion]
    }));
    return { questions: newQuestion };
  };

  removeQuestion(uniqueId, questions) {
    this.setState(({ questions }) => {
      var questionRemoved = this.state.questions.filter(
        props => props.uniqueId !== uniqueId
      );
      return { questions: questionRemoved };
    });
    console.log(
      "remove button",
      uniqueId,
      JSON.stringify(this.state.questions, null, " ")
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="questions">
        <ol id="quesitonsList">
          {this.state.questions.map((value, index) => (
            <li key={value.uniqueId}>
              {
                <RemoveQuestionButton
                  onClick={this.removeQuestion}
                  value={value.uniqueId}
                />
              }
              {
                <Question
                  onUpdate={this.handleUpdate}
                  value={value}
                  number={index}
                  updateAnswers={(answers) => this.updateAnswers(answers, value.uniqueId) }
                />
              }
              {<br />}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ol>
        <AddQuestionButton onClick={this.addQuestion} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Question extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: props.value.question,
      uniqueId: props.value.uniqueId,
      answers: props.value.answers,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({
      question: value
    });
    this.props.onUpdate({
      uniqueId: this.state.uniqueId,
      value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id={"questionDiv" + questionIdx} key={myUUID + questionIdx + 1}>
        Question<br />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.question}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          key={this.state.uniqueId}
          name="question"
        />
        <DropZone />
        <Answers updateAnswers={this.props.updateAnswers} answers={this.state.answers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class IntroFields extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      author: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log([name]);
    this.setState((previousState, props) => ({
      [name]: value
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="IntroFields">
        Title:{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="title"
        />
        Author:{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.author}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="author"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AddQuestionButton extends Component {
  addQuestion = () => {
    this.props.onClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="addQuestionButtonDiv">
        <button id="button" onClick={this.addQuestion} />
        <label id="addQuestionButton" onClick={this.addQuestion}>
          Add Question
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RemoveQuestionButton extends Component {
  removeQuestion = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="removeQuestionButtonDiv">
        <button id="button" onClick={this.removeQuestion} key={uuid()} />
        <label
          id="removeQuestionButton"
          onClick={this.removeQuestion}
          key={uuid()}
        >
          Remove Question
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class BuilderForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="formDiv">
        <IntroFields />
        <Questions />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default BuilderForm;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! This makes a lot more sense now. I will take this way of thinking and apply it to my dropzone components as well, :) Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have an idea as to how I would go about doing this for the `DropZone` component? I have been trying to get it together but I don't seem to be doing it right.